# How to extract the lines that contain g__something within it but does not followed by s__something in the following text?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to extract out those lines that contain `g__something` not followed by `s__something` in the lines. How can I do that?

[Here's my text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDyja.png)

Comment: No @karel. Actually that post is also mine. But I put that wrong. I have replied there. And soon going to remove that.

Comment: what happens with 'grep "g__" inputfile | grep -v "s__" > outputfile' ? It is a simple and basic way of doing it, I suppose that there are other possibile solutions, faster and more optimised than this one

Comment: thanks @Lorenz Keel. It works. What if I want to keep the first two lines as well?

Comment: Try this: 'head -2 inputfile > outputfile; grep "g__" inputfile | grep -v "s__" >> outputfile' Pay attention to >>, is not a mistake: it has the purpose to append the new line without overwriting.

Comment: @DEEP please add **all** your requirements in the body of your question. Please also post a textual example of your input and desired output. [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?)

Answer (score 2):

This awk command will unconditionally print the first two lines of `file` and print other lines that contain `g__` except where it is followed by `s__`

```
awk 'NR<3 || /g__/ && !/g__.*s__/' file
```

Note that this solution will print lines where `s__` *precedes* `g__`. If you want to exclude lines containing `s__` regardless of whether it comes before or after `g__`, change the second condition to `!/s__/`

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in python3. The following program will print lines containing "g__" but not containing "s__".

Paste this in a file called `find_g.py` and put the data in `data.txt`

```
import sys

# Open the file for reading
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:

    # Print first two lines without any condition
    print(f.readline(), end='')
    print(f.readline(), end='')

    # Check for condition in rest of the file
    for line in f:
        if "g__" in line and "s__" not in line:
            print(line, end='')
```

Then,

```
python3 find_g.py data.txt
```

Comment: A suggestion: Either use this or the one given by @steeldriver. If you have a huge data set, grep solutions can occupy big amount of memory.

Comment: I agree with @turbulence, as I stated in my answer as well. I don't know python and my knowledge of awk is limited, these two solutions are more elegant and effective than mine ^_^'

Comment: @Lorenz Keel Even I am not much of the awk syntax. But AFAIK, awk matches the given expression line-by-line, thus does not need to load the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are: extract the first two lines and then the lines that contain the pattern "g__" but not "s__"

One simple way is the following:

```
head -2 inputfile > outputfile; grep "g__" inputfile | grep -v "s__" >> outputfile
```

The part before ';' extract the first two lines of inputfile and put them in outputfile.
The part after ';' at first extract all lines containing "g__" and then, among them, remove the ones with the pattern "s__". These lines are then appended using >> operator in outputfile, so that the lines added before are not overwritten.

This is a very simple approach to the problem. For sure there are other solutions in terms of performances (maybe awk works better in case of huge files) and maybe more elegant than this one.